# TypoScript: Getting Video from Resources

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I'd like to get the video I added in page resources tab with TypoScript, similar like a header-image in TYPO3 10.4

I tried width IMG_RESOURCE but it doesn't work.

Here's my TS-snippet so far:

```
lib.HEADERIMG = IMG_RESOURCE
lib.HEADERIMG {
      file {
        import =  uploads/media/
        import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
        treatIdAsReference = 1
        import.listNum = 0
      }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the FILES object introduced in TYPO3 v6.0:

```
lib.headerMedia = FILES
lib.headerMedia {
  references {
    table = pages
    uid.data = page:uid
    fieldName = media
  }
}
```

See: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/ContentObjects/Files/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas Löffler, he pointed me in the right direction.
Here's my code:

```
lib.HEADERMEDIA = FILES
lib.HEADERMEDIA {
  references {
    table = pages
    uid.data = page:uid
    fieldName = media
 }
 renderObj = COA
 renderObj {
   20 = TEXT
   20.data = file:current:publicUrl
   20.wrap = <source src="|" type="video/mp4" />
 } 
}
```

Thank you!